# AssertionFailedError testing JPA interface in a service

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, junit

I'm trying to create a test for a method in a Service class. My method can throw exception is user exists:

```
@Override
public UserDto setProjectUser(UserDto userDto, String projectKeyId) {
    UserDto returnValue;
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new CustomMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

    if (userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail()) != null)
        throw new UserServiceException("Record already exists");
    ...

}
```

**In my test method that tests the exception throwing I implemented this code:**

```
@Test
void setProjectUser_throwsException() {
    Exception exception = assertThrows(UserServiceException.class, () -> {
        when(userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail())).thenReturn(any(UserModel.class));
    });
    assertEquals("Record already exists",
            exception.getMessage());
}
```

**First I imported my Jpa interface - I also tried using @MockBean annotation:**

```
@Mock
UserRepository userRepository;
```

**Then in my setUp method i initiated the mocks**

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    // i have implemented several object such as UserDto 
    userDto = new UserDto();
    userDto.setEmail("test@test.fr");
    ....
}
```

**My issue is that I obtain :**

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected UserServiceException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `setProjectUser()` inside `assertThrows`? Also `any(UserModel.class)` is designed for matching call parameters, **not** specifying return values. Just use `.thenReturn(new User())`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i completed this test :

```
@Test
void testSetProjectUser_ExceptionThrown() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new CustomMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
    // we pass an empty object
    UserDetailsRequestModel userDetailsRequestModel = UserDetailsRequestModel.builder().build();

    // check exceptions
    UserServiceException exception;

    // check mail if required fields are empty or not
    userDetailsRequestModel.setEmail("");
    userDetailsRequestModel.setFirstName("");
    userDetailsRequestModel.setLastName("");
    userDetailsRequestModel.setPassword("");
    exception = assertThrows(UserServiceException.class, () -> {
        registrationController
                .setProjectUser(
                        userDetailsRequestModel,
                        projectRequestModels.get(0).getProjectKeyId()
                );

    });
    assertEquals(
            "Missing required field. Please check documentation for required fields",
            exception.getMessage()
    );
}
```